# Windows form application hangs with - "In a sleep, wait, or join"

Tags: multithreading, winforms, join, sleep, wait

We have windows form application which is single threaded (there are couple of forms that has some background worker process) but mainly single threaded. Due to some reason the application is getting hanged. This happens when the PC going to Sleep and PC locks the screen.

I can break the debugger in Visual Studio but the only thing I get is "In a sleep, wait, or join". And that is literately what I get.

First, what this "In a sleep, wait, or join" means? Second, How can get more information on what is causing this? Any other tips will me much appreciated.

Thx

Comment: This doesn't just happen randomly...you're doing something to cause it.  Explain more about what your application does and how you're using "some background worker process"...

Comment: Application is very complex with thousands of forms etc ... so hard to explain. There are a few screens that has Backgroundworkers the payment processing screen and the Main window. I suspect the main window has some role in this. The main window is using private BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(); to populate the Menu three outside the UI thread. It is defined in the module level and then does the work in the Do_Work sub and passes the details to BackgroundWorkerAsync_ProgressChanged to update the UI.